# Access to Action for Admin and for anonymous users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I want to add new users via Admin (just create new user), but in same time anonymous users can register themselfs. 
So i override Authorize Attribute (but now it's only for Admin access).

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly EnumUserType[] _allowedroles;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params EnumUserType[] roles)
    {
        this._allowedroles = roles;
        _userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorize = false;
        foreach (var role in _allowedroles)
        {
            var currRole = role;
            var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
            var user = _userService.GetMany(m => m.Id == userId
                                                 && m.Type == currRole && !m.Deleted).Result;

            if (user.Any())
            {
                authorize = true;
            }
        }
        return authorize;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Note : Admin isn't Identity Role in my case. It's custom field 'Type'.

So problem - how to allow anonymous users have access with this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but if you want to allow anonymous users then why use the authorize attribute at all? You really should be separating concerns here and have a sign up page with anonymous access and a separate page for admin functions that is protected by your authorize attribute.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Problem i have is next - I want to add users as Admin also. And this is what comes to my head. Nothing else...

Comment: Just create two pages. One for users to sign up, and the other that is protected for you to add users. On your admin page you can add users and set their roles such as Admin. That would make you the super user that has the right to add users as admins. Your authorize attribute would need to reflect that with a super user role otherwise other admins could add users as admins.

Comment: And if we talk about single page application?

Comment: There's no difference. A single page application is not a single page of code, it's multiple modules loaded into and out of a shell. Just make one module for each.